# WordPress meta query check the current users in meta value array

Tags: wordpress, meta-query

I am having trouble to query cpt for the current user if s/he is in the meta value array.

## query args

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => $cp::get_module_cpt(),
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'meta_query'     => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key'     => 'premium_module',
            'value'   => 0,
            'compare' => '=',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_users',
            'value'   => get_current_user_id(),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ],
    ],
];
```

## meta key

`permit_users`

## meta value

#### if has value

#### Database

```
a:5:{i:0;s:2:"23";i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:1:"6";i:3;s:1:"7";i:4;s:2:"27";}
```

#### In PHP

```
Array
(
    [0] => 29
    [1] => 28
    ...
)
```

#### if has no value

return false or empty array. Depends if ever set the field before.

#### additionally,

I have tried setting compare to `=` equal but that also didn't work. Probably since the value is in array.

### Result Looking

The query should return all posts that have current user id in the `permit_users` key.

> **Important:**
>   The `permit_users` is an optional, so if the field has not value (false) or empty array, the query should ignore it.

## Update

I have tried compare with `LIKE` that seems working. But is it good to compare serialized data? What if current user is `11` and value has `111` user in it?

Comment: Could you post the sample value stored in the DB for the meta `permit_users`

Comment: It's a serialized and I tried with `LIKE` that seems working but what about if field is not set or empty? And searching in serialized data using `LIKE` is a good? What will happen if the current user id is `11` and the meta value has user id `111` ? I am updating question with db value.

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan I have update question, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is if this Custom Post Type is developed by you means try to unserialize and save each user in individual row something like this

meta_key in the format `permit_users_{user_id}` with the value `user_id`.

Save values in the above format with meta unique is set to `true` (the last parameter)

```
add_post_meta( 68, 'permit_users_' . get_current_user_id(), '21', true );
```

Else your project DB is now mature very much and difficult to do the above suggestion change then you can use the below meta query

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => $cp::get_module_cpt(),
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'meta_query'     => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key'     => 'premium_module',
            'value'   => 0,
            'compare' => '=',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_users',
            'value'   => sprintf(':"%s";', get_current_user_id()),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
    ],
];
```

The above one will work with serialized data with the value `11`, `111` but please consider this as a temporary solution.

Again I'm requesting you to try to implement the conversion of serialized data into an individual own row of values.

Additional note: if serialized string is very lengthy and in worst case matching querying user id from the lengthy string will take time. So maintain this serialized data in shorter length but don't get worry and do early optimization wait till slow query log record this then we can go for optimized solution like adding indexing or adding a new search engine layer for e.g. Elastic search.

Comment: Thanks a lot for great details. Since, I have many posts already that will make bit harder to change the existing data. But I consider that suggestion and will implement that later. For now if `sprintf(':"%s";', get_current_user_id())` works than I can move on with it. Thanks again.

Comment: It's my pleasure to resolve your problem. Thank you.

Comment: It will work for that case to because inside the `%s` the 1 i.e. user id will be interpolated here is the e.g. `get_current_user_id()` return 1 means the final string look like `:"1";` same is applicable for user id `11` too. If you face any failure or not getting expected result check the last executed query in `WP`. Please feel free to ask more queries no problem at all.